# Como verificar se um diretório está vazio ou se há um arquivo existente na pasta?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Eu gostaria de saber como posso verificar se um diretório (pasta) está vazio e se um arquivo já existe ou não nela em NodeJS. Exemplo:

```
const fs = require("fs");

// recebeJson é a pasta que precisa ser verificada se está vazia.
fs.readFile("./recebeJson", function(err, data) {

    if (err){
        return console.log("Arquivo vazio");
    }

    // se caso não estiver vazia ela retornaria a chamada de outro script.
    else {
        return ("./verificacaoJson.js");
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Para verificar se um arquivo existe em um diretório, utilize a função `fs.exists` (deprecated) ou então a função `fs.existsSync`. Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```
const filename = "file.txt";

if (fs.existsSync(filename)) {
    // Code ...
}
```

Para verificar se um diretório está vazio ou não, você pode utilizar a função `fs.readdir` ou a função `fs.readdirSync` para obter um array com todos os arquivos de um diretório.

Dessa forma, basta verificar o tamanho deste array para saber se o diretório está vazio ou não.

```
const path = ".";
const isEmpty = fs.readdirSync(path).length > 0 ? false : true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar o método `readdir` do `fs` e no *callback*, verificar se existem arquivos, utilizando o `length`:

```
fs.readdir(diretorio, function(err, files) {
    if (err) {
        console.error("Erro na leitura do diretório:", err);
    } else {
        if (files.length) {
            console.log(`O diretório '${diretorio}' possui arquivos ou pastas.`);
        } else {
            console.log(`O diretório '${diretorio}' está vazio.`);
        }
    }
});
```

> Veja online: https://repl.it/repls/PalatableMelodicSign

---

A mesma ideia pode ser implementada utilizando do método `readdirSync`:

```
if (fs.readdirSync(diretorio).length) {
    console.log(`O diretório '${diretorio}' possui arquivos ou pastas.`);
} else {
    console.log(`O diretório '${diretorio}' está vazio.`);
}
```

> Veja online: https://repl.it/repls/AnimatedIllfatedComments

---

> Documentação: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html